# open incoming UDP port in android mobile phone

Tags: android, mobile, udp, p2p

For a certain test I need to make a P2P connection between two mobile devices (running android). I can get assign a publicly routable static ips for the mobile devices. I need to know whether is it possible to open a UDP port inside a device for which the other device can directly push content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, provided you are not attempting to bind to a restricted port and the port is free.

App I'm currently working in is listening for incoming P2P SIP on 5062.

```
$ adb -s 018a99b858b628cb shell netstat -an | grep 5062
udp        0      0 192.168.96.93:5062      0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer. Are you executing this command in the linux terminal of which the device is attached? and what is this number 018a99b858b628cb. Thank you.

Comment: The command I added was an adb command to show the output of the netstat command from the device.  The netstat -an shows all active ports on the device and the state.  I greped for the specific port to filter out the other output.  The adb -s flag is used to specify a specific USB device, since I have multiple devices attached.  There are a good number of links in the Related section related to listening on UDP.

Comment: being able to bind a port is not evidence for it being able to accept unsolicited requests, e.g. a firewall rule might interfere